Custom compiler errors/warnings
I own a LaTeX project with many contributors that don't necessarily use LaTeX every day so they often make "little mistakes" as writing ... instead of \dots in mathmode or using nonadaptive parentheses and similar.
Is there a way to define additional rules for compiler so that these little mistakes would cause compiler to throw warnings like Hey, you'd be better with \dots here instead of ...?
I am mostly interested in a solution that would not require me to modify the compiler itself but rather *.cls we are using because we collaborate on Overleaf.
Thanks in advance for your help.

You can write a script (e.g. using perl, awk or even lua) that searches for such mistakes. For some mistakes also lacheck or nag could be used.

try chktex program that comes with texlive and does exactly that sort of thing.  Personally I don't use it because it doesn't like my tex, but see how you get on
